# Extjs Treepanel - How to delete root of a tree

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4.1

I have a tree panel with local data like

```
 root: {
            text: 'root',
            children: [
                { text: "child"
                  leaf: true
                }]
 ....
}
```

first: I want to delete root of tree. I try below code but that not working for root. However that work for another node (`node.remove(true)`)

```
tree.getRootNode().remove(true);
```

second: I want to remove all tree (i think this like remove root?)

 How can i do that thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stated in [Ext doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-remove), the `Ext.dataNodeInterface.remove`:

> Removes this node from its parent

Root node has no parent, so `remove` won't work. However, to remove the whole tree from treepanel, you can try:

```
treepanel.setRootNode(null);
```

I have created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ceV5caP50nTi0OYV1YCm) to demonstrate a few examples you might be interested in.

Comment: I use setRootNode(null); but it's not working in extjs 4.1 :(

Comment: @freestyle I updated my plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/ceV5caP50nTi0OYV1YCm to use 4.1.0, it works as expected. Can you create a plunk or jsfiddle to show what isn't working for you?

Comment: In your fiddle, I click the button, whole tree is removed, but an dummy root node is added by the treepanel. Is this your problem? You can set `rootVisible` to false to hide the root node. Or, can you state your purpose of removing tree from treepanel? Maybe there are better ways to achieve the end result.

Comment: I try to work with tree panel and i have above problem. I think u're right to slove my problem that is set rootVisible to false. Thank u :)